# Communicate between NodeJS and C++

Tags: c++, node.js

I'm doing a project that tracks objects with AR.Drone 2.0 using NodeJS.
I get a video from drone through NodeJS server.
And I want to use CMT (Main website: http://www.gnebehay.com/cmt/) (GitHub Repository: https://github.com/gnebehay/CppMT).

But I don't know how to do that.

I want to send a video from NodeJS to CMT(c++) and after processing, send back the point of object center and rectangle coordinate from CMT to NodeJS.
Everything should do in real time.

Would someone have an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start from [here](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html).
Write your plugin, bind it to whatever you want and send back and forth the data form C++ to the js environment.

Comment: Actually I found that before, but I ignored it. Because I didn't know exactly that is what I found. But if you tell that, then I will try it. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. Do not forget to accept a response once you find one that fits your needs. It will help future users and their searches.

Comment: Hey, I tried it, and I succeed to communicate nodejs and cpp. But what I want to exchange is image buffer data and I don't know how to convert the v8 object to Mat type in cpp after I send the data. If you know that, please give me more advice. Thank you.

Comment: I guess you should accept the response and close this question, then open a new one, for what you are asking now is pretty unrelated with this issue.

Comment: Got it. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: As of today, even the most basic example mentioned in the repo fail to compile. Disappointing.